# Error while loading ressource for a WebSite (wordpress)

Tags: javascript, php, wordpress

I'm encountering an error like:

> pageguide.min.css:1 Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 ()
>   pageguide.min.js:1 Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 ()

The folder that contains these files is already on my server.
This how I apply (pastebin file).

[This is the pastebin](https://pastebin.com/eER1AJiZ)

```
<script src="pageguide-1.3.2/dist/js/pageguide.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="pageguide-1.3.2/dist/css/pageguide.min.css">
<script>
$(document).ready(function () {
    tl.pg.init({});
});
</script>
```

Thanks for your help.

[EDIT]
After trying all your solutions I got this :

> GET https://crushonapp.com/wp-content/themes/bigcartpageguide-1.3.2/dist/css/pageguide.min.css net::ERR_ABORTED 404
>   pixel.js?id=feca3ba1b1545:1 poptin-start
>   (index):139 GET https://connect.facebook.net/en_US/fbevents.js net::ERR_BLOCKED_BY_CLIENT
>   (anonymous) @ (index):139
>   (anonymous) @ (index):139
>   (index):419 GET https://crushonapp.com/wp-content/themes/bigcartpageguide-1.3.2/dist/js/pageguide.min.js net::ERR_ABORTED 404
>   pixel.js?id=feca3ba1b1545:1 initiatePullPoptinsRequest()
>   (index):420 GET https://crushonapp.com/wp-content/themes/bigcartpageguide-1.3.2/dist/css/pageguide.min.css net::ERR_ABORTED 404
>   (index):422 Uncaught TypeError: $ is not a function
>       at (index):422

Comment: The files you are loading are not in that path

Comment: You must have an incorrect path to these files

Comment: Show us where these files are on your server, relevant to the DocumentRoot

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to include stylesheet and js as below

```
<script src="<?php echo get_template_directory_uri().'/pageguide-1.3.2/dist/js/pageguide.min.js';?>"></script>

<link rel="stylesheet" href="<?php echo get_template_directory_uri().'/pageguide-1.3.2/dist/css/pageguide.min.css';?>">
```

Note: This will work if your files structure is like **wp-content/themes/your-theme/pageguide-1.3.2/**

Hope this helps

Comment: Have you loot the Pastebin ?

Answer (score 0):

If the `pageguide-1.3.2` folder is in your root, you can use `src="<?php bloginfo('url'); ?>/pageguide-1.3.2/dist/js/pageguide.min.js"`

If the folder is within your theme you can use `src="<?php bloginfo('template_directory'); ?>/pageguide-1.3.2/dist/js/pageguide.min.js"`

Comment: Have you loot the Pastebin ?

Comment: Yes, but that doesn't tell us where the files are on your server. Your src path needs to be relative to the location of those files.

Answer (score 0):

"pageguide-1.3.2/dist/" doesn't look like a proper path.
Check where your source lies on the server and copy the path into your code.

An absolute path should look something like this `http://localhost/pageguide-1.3.2/dist/`